# writing function to file, getting none

Tags: python, output

I'm trying to write psutil.test() to a file but i can't get it to work. Is there anyway to do this?

This is the code im using:

```
import psutil
import tkMessageBox

def Sysinfo():
 test = psutil.test()
 tkMessageBox.showinfo(title='testing',message=test)
 FILE = open("sysinfo.txt","w")
 FILE.write(str(test))
 FILE.close()

Sysinfo()
```

The file contains the line "None".

In prompt psutils.test() shows :

USER         PID %CPU %MEM     VSZ     RSS TTY           START    TIME  COMMAND
root           1  0.0  0.1    3532    1944 ?             14:23   00:00  init
root           2  0.0    ?       ?       ? ?             14:23   00:00  kthreadd
root           3  0.0    ?       ?       ? ?             14:23   00:00  ksoftirqd/0
root           5  0.0    ?       ?       ? ?             14:23   00:00  kworker/u:0
root           6  0.0    ?       ?       ? ?             14:23   00:00  migration/0
etc..

Comment: do you have the necessary permissions to write to the directory?

Comment: What value does `psutil.test()` return?

Comment: What do you mean, "can't get it to work"? What does sysinfo.txt show?

Comment: test is None after running test = psutil.test(). Maybe psutil.test() doesn't return anything, just prints the result?

Comment: @PrototypeStark yes i have the rights. I added the prompt output and the output that i get in the text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
def SysInfo():
  oldstdout = sys.stdout
  sys.stdout = open("sysinfo.txt","w")
  psutil.test()
  sys.stdout.close()
  sys.stdout = oldstdout
SysInfo()
```

This will redirect the stdout to the file, write to it and then give you the correct answer.

Comment: I'm getting NameError: global name 'close' is not defined

Comment: Probably should be `sys.stdout.close()` ... I actually saw this wrapped up in a context manager somewhere ... very cool

Comment: I do not know why this works. But im happy it does. Thanks! @PrototypeStark and mglison

Comment: @HeWhoStudies It works because I have rerouted the output of psutil.test() to another file.

Comment: @HeWhoStudies selecting an answer is SO's way of saying thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

`psutil.test()` only prints the result, it doesn't have a return statement. Try this:

```
import inspect
import psutil
test_source_code = inspect.getsource(psutil.test)
print test_source_code
```

You can search a `return` statement like this:

```
test_source_code.find('return') yields `-1`
```

Here is how the psutil.test() ends:

```
            print_(templ % (user[:10],
                        pinfo['pid'],
                        pinfo['cpu_percent'],
                        memp,
                        vms,
                        rss,
                        pinfo.get('terminal', '') or '?',
                        ctime,
                        cputime,
                        pinfo['name'].strip() or '?'))
```

HINT: Here is a convenient way of reading python code in a terminal. 
(Do `pip install pygments` first!)

```
import pygments
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer
from pygments.formatters import TerminalFormatter
from pygments import highlight

print hightlight(test_source_code, PythonLexer(), TerminalFormatter())
```